# Looking for GeoJSON describing French departments?

Tags: shapefile, data, geojson, france

Is there any place where I could find a GeoJSON describing the borders of the French departments, or do I have to convert a shapefile?

Comment: So do you already have a shapefile that you could convert?

Comment: I think I found one, but I'm having problem converting it. Source: http://professionnels.ign.fr/geofla#tab-3

Comment: Did you see [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41465/generating-geojson-with-python)?

Comment: No. Will look at it.

Comment: I tried using this site but It returns an error. http://ogre.adc4gis.com/

Comment: {"error":true,"message":"Ogre can't transform files of type: shp","file":"DEPARTEMENT.shp"}

Comment: I did it. I was supposed to upload a .zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converted

**Télécharger GEOFLA® Communes France Métropolitaine (7z de 10,2 Mo)**

> in QGIS (1.9) to Geojson.
>
> Opened the Shapefile Save as (set Projected CRS to WGS84) then save as
>   geojson.

produced a 38mb file

First Feature is:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID_GEOFLA": 1, "CODE_COMM": "271", "INSEE_COM": "29271", "NOM_COMM": "SAINT-VOUGAY", "STATUT": "Commune simple", "X_CHF_LIEU": 1743, "Y_CHF_LIEU": 68564, "X_CENTROID": 1737, "Y_CENTROID": 68559, "Z_MOYEN": 88, "SUPERFICIE": 1483, "POPULATION": 0.9, "CODE_CANT": "31", "CODE_ARR": "3", "CODE_DEPT": "29", "NOM_DEPT": "FINISTERE", "CODE_REG": "53", "NOM_REGION": "BRETAGNE" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -4.118903168643321, 48.578705252887637 ], [ -4.133082643444328, 48.576480950956991 ], [ -4.146945477311765, 48.563489275679281 ], [ -4.166442439675465, 48.563360932190648 ], [ -4.169087363761147, 48.567166467326842 ], [ -4.166757747834486, 48.587196857780164 ], [ -4.170044099950427, 48.593781771768079 ], [ -4.153039120902795, 48.605230824638262 ], [ -4.147281236177197, 48.621672693490268 ], [ -4.14031024195557, 48.618316601929457 ], [ -4.128991709014402, 48.607354414033459 ], [ -4.120018547829471, 48.605670949843812 ], [ -4.118919653959254, 48.599008102939585 ], [ -4.126460935034522, 48.595096434191902 ], [ -4.128464714954705, 48.588527259565346 ], [ -4.11877419698558, 48.582054835673347 ], [ -4.118903168643321, 48.578705252887637 ] ] ] } }
```

Can upload it zipped if you require?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I managed to convert it using http://ogre.adc4gis.com/.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenStreetMap’s French community are maintaining a rather exhaustive and accurate set of maps. Whether you’re a cartographer, a graphic designer or a developer, they’ve made it easy to reuse their work. As a matter of fact, from the OpenStreetMap’s OSM format, they’ve exported the maps to various formats such as Shapefiles, SVG, GeoJSON (to mention a few of them).

And the good news is that all their contributions are released on the French Open Data platform, under a ODbl license: https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/organizations/openstreetmap/

So here it is: the French towns’ boundaries dataset: https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/decoupage-administratif-communal-francais-issu-d-openstreetmap/

Answer (score 0):

Someone exported French cities, departments and regions data as geojson, from the official National Geographic Institute (IGN). Free to use and open (Open Licence, compatible with CC-BY 2.0) : https://github.com/gregoiredavid/france-geojson