# Geometry workflow from Shapely to GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, mapbox, shapely, url

I'm undertaking a fairly simple workflow all within a python script with the goal of passing urlencoded GeoJSON in a URL to the Mapbox static API:

1. create a point from DD string in `EPSG:4326`:
2. convert to UTM for easier units and buffer the point generating a polygon
3. transform back to WGS84 for the API
4. generate valid, URL encoded GeoJSON string.

My hangup is the last part. I've used Shapely and pyproj to conduct 1-3 but using:

`json.dumps(mapping(<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x106a22690>))` (and several permutations of this) and encoding it using `urlencode` or `url_quote` generates an encoded URL with JSON that returns 'Invalid Geojson' from Mapbox.

I am optimistic that the `geojson` library may solve this, but I can't seem to find a simple way to convert a shapely Polygon object to a GeoJSON polygon object.

Comment: Without a real example, we can do nothing an `json.dumps(mapping(<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x106a22690>))` is not a correct formulation

Comment: apologies and update: `geojson.dumps(mapping(poly))` where `poly` is a valid shapely polygon geometry generates valid geojson. my challenge at this point is to encode it in such a way that the mapbox api doesn't reject it.

Comment: look at [Mapbox: Add a GeoJSON polygon](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/)

Comment: thanks @gene I'm working with the static API. just tried the `mapbox-sdk-py` as well and get a `422` server response with valid python geojson object... this feels like it should be easy. I must be missing something...

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41465/generating-geojson-with-python check this link out

Answer (score 2):

Decided to use the [`mapbox-sdk-py`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-py) library instead. Works well but the pipeline from shapely to a map-able feature using the SDK is a little cumbersome (per this [issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-py/issues/132))

Need to add some features to the shapley (`geom`, below) object and encapsulate it in a list:

`feature = [{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {}, 'geometry': mapping(geom)}]`

for the [`Static`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-py/blob/master/docs/static.md#static-maps) method to work.

Thanks [@perrygeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/300/perrygeo) and [@sgillies](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/390/sgillies) for the hints.

Comment: What way is to avoid sequence of tuples in coordinates? It returns in mapping(geom): ` 'coordinates': ((37.353705999999995, 55.98468299999999), (37.353929229834065, 55.98471677959936),...` I would like the native sequence of lists instead